# creating a new asset catalog / image set in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, ipad

Im really confused when creating an asset catalog in Xcode6 to use with the new single abstract storyBoard. Im trying to create a set of differnt backGround images to fit all devices.  When creating a new image set, from the Attribute Inspector I selected Universal for devices with width Any Height Any. Now I get 3 small windows to drag and drop images in as follows:

- 1x
- 2x
- 3x

How do I insert (drag & drop) all of the following images (same image / different size) into the above 3 small windows ?

- iphone3.5@2x.png (640 x 960):
- iphone5.png (640 x 1136):
- iphone6.png (750 x 1334):
- iphone6plus.png (2208 x 1242):
- ipad.png (768 x 1024):
- ipad.png (1536 x 2048):

Answer (score 1):

Select your **Target >General > App Icon and Launch Images> Use Asset Catalog** next to **App Icon Source** and **Launch Images Sources** there would be arrow button click that.

Now just drag and drop your launch images you want to support to appropriate image size placeholder.

Comment: sorry but that procedure is for setting up Launch images. I want to set up  a new image set. Select image.xcassets > select the add sign > select new image set and then I'm stuck ??